# putting doubles in descending order

Tags: c#, double

I'm making a Console application that represents an Auto Parts store, and I have a catalogue with parts and other supplies.

How would I put the Cost of all the products in order from highest to lowest, along with the name of each part, when I enter a command like "Return Cost High to low"?

Here's the relevant code:

```
public class AutoPart
{
    public string Name;
    public double Cost;
}

public class Liquid : AutoPart
{
    public new string Name;
    public new double Cost;      
    public double Quarts;  
}

public class tool : AutoPart
{
    public new string Name;               
    public new double Cost;
    public double SizeInMM;
}

public class Catalogue
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoPart Motorcraftoilfilter = new AutoPart();
        Motorcraftoilfilter.Name = "MotorCraft Oil Filter"; 
        Motorcraftoilfilter.Cost = 6.99;

        Liquid valvolineoil = new Liquid();
        valvolineoil.Name = "Valvoline Oil";
        valvolineoil.Cost = 8.99;
        valvolineoil.Quarts = 1;

        tool Wrench = new tool();
        Wrench.Name = "Duralast 13mm Wrench";
        Wrench.Cost = 16.99;
        Wrench.SizeInMM = 13;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no price in your code, do you mean cost?

Comment: yes my bad sorry

Comment: There is no list in your code, how can your sort if there is no list *scratches head* or am i missing something

Comment: is there a way to make a list?

Comment: You can make a list of the base class type and add all the other types to it. You will only have the properties available to sort by from the base class, but since it contains the `Cost` and `Name` properties, you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Remove unnecessary fields in the child class, because they inherit from AutoPart.

```
public class Liquid : AutoPart
{
    public string FluidType;  //this defines the type of fluid the product
    public double Quarts;     //this defines the quarts of the object
}

public class tool : AutoPart
{
    public double sizeinmm; //this declares the size of the tool in milimeters
}
```

Create a list to contain all autoparts

```
List<AutoPart> AllAutoParts = new List<AutoPart>
{
    Motorcraftoilfilter,
    valvolineoil,
    Wrench,
};
```

Then you can do the job

```
if (Console.ReadLine() == "Return Price High to low")
{
    foreach (var autopart in AllAutoParts.OrderByDescending(autopart => autopart.Cost))
        Console.WriteLine("Cost: {0}, Name: {1}", autopart.Cost, autopart.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As shingo mentioned, you can create a list of the base class type (`AutoPart`) and add all the other types to it. You will only have the base class properties available to order by, but since it contains the `Cost` and `Name` properties, you should be able to do what you want.

You can then use the `OrderByDescending` extension method (add `using System.Linq` to the top of your file), to order by the `Cost` from highest to lowest:

```
private static void Main(string[] cmdArgs)
{
    AutoPart motorCraftOilFilter = new AutoPart();
    motorCraftOilFilter.Name = "MotorCraft Oil Filter";
    motorCraftOilFilter.Cost = 6.99;

    Liquid valvolineOil = new Liquid();
    valvolineOil.Name = "Valvoline Oil";
    valvolineOil.Cost = 8.99;
    valvolineOil.Quarts = 1;

    Tool wrench = new Tool();
    wrench.Name = "Duralast 13mm Wrench";
    wrench.Cost = 16.99;
    wrench.SizeInMM = 13;

    var catalog = new List<AutoPart>
    {
        motorCraftOilFilter,
        valvolineOil,
        wrench
    };

    // Pretent the command to order products was entered
    // You can use OrderByDescending to order the items by 
    // Cost from Highest to Lowest
    catalog = catalog.OrderByDescending(part => part.Cost).ToList();

    // Output results
    catalog.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " " + item.Cost));

    Console.Write("\nPress any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

---

One thing to note about the way you designed your classes is that you don't need to create `new` fields that are already defined in the base class. That's one of the reasons to use inheritance is that you *inherit* these fields automatically.

Also, as a rule of thumb you should almost always use properties instead of fields for your public members. You can read about why [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja/).

This way, your classes are much simpler - only only add the *unique* properties to the child classes:

```
public class AutoPart
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}

public class Liquid : AutoPart
{
    public double Quarts { get; set; }
}

public class Tool : AutoPart
{
    public double SizeInMM { get; set; }
}
```